# Regex for Username and Password verification

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex for a username and password verification. For the username i want to allow A-Z a-Z 0-9 and these special characters: `@:.` I tried to use it so:

```
if(preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9@:.]/', $username)) {
      $this->err = 'error';
    }
```

But that doesnt work. And for the password i want that they have at least one uppercase one lowercase and a number.

Comment: Ok i trie but do you have a regex for the password verification?

Comment: @JohnConde, that is not the case since `.` is present inside of a class.

Comment: Hm, but why is this not working?

Comment: You need to anchor it and allow more than one. `^[A-Za-z0-9@:.]+$` It should be if !preg_match as well because that makes it a valid pass right?

Comment: Thanks do you also have a regex for the password verification?

Comment: You have an answer below for the password verification.

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: [I hate it when people limit passwords and user names](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [**anchor**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) your pattern and use lookahead to validate those cases.

```
if(preg_match('/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9@:.]+$/', $username)) { ... }
```

[`(?= ... )`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) is a zero-width assertion which does not consume any characters on the string.

Therefore, It only matches a position in the string. The point of zero-width is the validation to see if a regular expression can or cannot be matched looking ahead  from the current position, without adding to the overall match.

Comment: This is your password verification `for the password i want that they have at least one uppercase one lowercase and a number`..

Comment: And that is the reason why we have so much regex questions.